# How would I add ExternalInterface to this code to remove scroll bars and that sort of stuff?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I have this code here and it allows me to open a new popup but I don't want any of the scroll bars and stuff like that, I know I would need ExternalInterface but I have no idea where to put it can anyone help?

```
var url:String = "https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

try {
    navigateToURL(request, '_blank'); // second argument is target
}
catch (e:Error) {
    trace("Error occurred!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ExternalInterface.call('window.open', 'url', 'windowName', 'resizable=no, toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, status=no, directories=no');
```

But doing this would of course be subjectable to the usual ordeal of pop-up blocking and tabs being opened instead of windows and such. I would recommend calling a function to show a dialog containing an iframe instead.

Comment: Wherever you need the window triggered. A click handler maybe?

Comment: With a click handler would the popup start on its own?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but the questions your are asking show that you might need to go back to the basics of AS3 programming. Any further discussion here will render this thread off-topic. If you require additional help with other concrete problems, please do a search on SO and open up a new topic if you don't find the answers you need.